# Connection refused error in java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I've created an RMI service that includes some method calls from another computer. Server and client have valid IP addresses and when I try to run the program in the client I get a `connection refused` exception.

When I change the IP address to localhost it will solve my problem, but when I try remote to another IP address the same error occurs.

Comment: [tag:websocket] has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Micho Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases of 'connection refused' in RMI:

1. When calling `bind()/rebind()/unbind()`. The Registry isn't started at the host:port or URL you're using.
2. When calling `lookup()`. If (1) succeeded, you're trying to lookup the wrong Registry. The Registry normally runs at the same host as the server.
3. When calling a remote method. This means that you need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the server JVM before exporting any remote objects. See the RMI FAQ item A.1 for why. A better fix is to fix the DNS or `hosts` file.

Answer (score -1):

Try use this before register rmi

System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", REGISTRY_HOST);

here REGISTRY_HOST is the ip address.

Comment: You need to do this considerably prior to 'register RMI'. And if the Registry host is different from the server host it's the wrong host to use: you should use the server host. If they're the same you should therefore still use the server host IP.